# Is a new .war file uploaded to the webapps directory supposed to force tomcat restart?

Tags: web-applications, tomcat, ubuntu, tomcat7, war

I am putting together a new build environment and when I upload a new .war file, Tomcat does not seem to be unwrapping it into a directory structure, or restarting.

Does there have to be some setting that needs to be set for this?
I am using ubuntu.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, on `TOMCAT_HOME/conf`, there's `server.xml`. Look for the following:

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
```

- Setting `unpackWARs` to `true` allows Tomcat to unzip your WAR file to a directory structure.
- Setting `autoDeploy` to `true` allows Tomcat to auto deploy your web application if it detects a WAR file deployed in Tomcat.

Hope this helps!